# UITabBar buttons not resized iPad landscape Mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have added three view controllers to UITabbarController. I am getting the view of the buttons in tabBarController as shown below.

link:[image: http://i.imgur.com/7ugGWAu.png]

There is huge margin from left and right, I want to remove that. Although in iPhone its working fine and there is not a padding from left and right. is that possible in iPad?

Comment: anyone please answer. I am stucked

Answer (score 0):

You must put this code in viewWillLayoutSubviews of your UITabBarController. It available IOS 7.0 and later.

```
self.tabBar.itemPositioning = UITabBarItemPositioningFill;
```